# MySql query to get user email from related table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 related tables:

**Table 1 (user):**

1. userID_usr
2. Username_usr
3. UserEmail_usr

**Table 2 (paylogs)**

4. ID_pay
5. UserID_pay

As result I was to list ALL rows from Table (paylogs) with related Username_usr and UserEmail_usr.

Result example:

1. JoeDoe JD@gmail.com
2. AnaDoe AD@gmail.com
3. TerSam @TS@aol.com

Could some one please kindly help me with this query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple join:

```
SELECT ID_pay, Username_usr, UserEmail_usr
FROM paylogs JOIN user ON UserID_pay = userID_usr
```